# Java.lang.NullPointerException error. Checking for a null object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, linked-list

So what I'm trying to do here is to check if an object exists or not through `if(x.next==null)` and I'm getting an error for that which won't let me access a null object. I also get the same error when trying to modify an object for e.g. `x.next=y`

The code is simple, it's just to implement a linked list. 
Thanks!

```
//import SingleLinkedList1.Node;

public class SingleLinkedList2 implements ISimpleList2 {

private class Node
{   int    value;
    Node   next; }

private Node first;
private Node last;    


public void insertFront(int item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Node oldfirst = first;

    // Create the new node
    Node newfirst = new Node();
    newfirst.value = item;
    newfirst.next = oldfirst;

    // Set the new node as the first node
    first = newfirst;
    if(oldfirst.next==null){
        last=first;
    }
}

public int removeFront() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Save the previous first
    Node oldfirst = first;

    if(oldfirst.next==null){
        last=null;
    }

    // Follow the first's node (possibly empty)
    // and set the first to that pointer
    first = oldfirst.next;

    // Return the value of old first 
    return oldfirst.value;

}

public void insertEnd(int item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Node newLast=new Node();
    newLast.value=item;
    last.next=newLast;

    last=newLast;

}

public int removeEnd() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Node oldLast=last;
    Node check=new Node();
    check=first;
    while(check.next!=last ){
        check=check.next;
    }
    last=check;

    return oldLast.value;

}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if(first.next==null){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}


}
```

Comment: More info oon how this is invoked would help. Looks like first and last are never initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite common.
You have to ensure that the object itself isn't null.

In your check `if(x.next==null)` the evaluation of `x.next` throws a NullPointerException because x itself is Null.

E.g. In the isEmpty method you have to check if(first==null)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check `x` that can be null..

like in code `f(x == null)`, because if `x` is null then you will get `NullPointException`.